# Order of parameter pack expansion

Tags: c++, templates, io, variadic-templates

I have 2 functions to read binary file.

1st function reads `sizeof(T)` bytes from file:

```
template<typename T>
T read() { ... some IO operations ... };
```

2nd function calls first one multiple times with each template parameter:

```
template<typename... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...> read_all() {
    return std::make_tuple(read<Ts>()...);
};
```

Everything works fine except of 1st function call order. For something like

```
uint32_t a;
uint8_t b;
std::tie(a, b) = read_all<uint32_t, uint8_t>();
```

the first will be called `read<uint8_t>()` and after that `read<uint32>()` which reverses order of passing template parameters and messes up with order of bytes in file.

Sure, I can call `read_all` with reversed order of template arguments and get right order in the end, but is there a more obvious way to do so?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

C++ does not specify the order in which a function's arguments are evaluated. If the expressions to a function all consume data from a stream, you can get behavior where objects are read in the wrong order.

Braced initializer lists are evaluated from left to right, however, so you should get better results if you try something like:

```
template<typename... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...> read_all() {
    return std::tuple<Ts...>{read<Ts>()...};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would keep it a bit simpler and do this:

```
uint32_t a;
uint8_t b;
std::tie(a, b) = read<std::tuple<uint32_t, uint8_t>>();
```

This way there's only a single `read()` and you can even skip the `tie()` if you use the tuple (or struct) fields directly.