# How can C++ differentiate between () and {} when init a vector

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1(10);
    std::vector<int> v2{10};

    for (int x : v1)
        std::cout << x << ", ";

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int x : v2)
        std::cout << x << ", ";
}
```

makes

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
10,
```

How can C++ distinguish between () and {} when initialising a class?

And how can I create a constructor for both () and {} with different meanings?

Comment: They're different characters. You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: `{}` is using an initialization list, so it actually initializes the vector with those values. `()` is just providing an initial size of the vector, in this case 10 ints, all initialized to 0.

Comment: The `{}` constructor has `std::initializer_list` as parameter. As this example proves, you should never initialize standard containers with `{}`, use either `()` or `= {}` (if the vector had some other element type (not constructible from `int`), `vec{10}` would've filled it with 10 elements).

Comment: This is a duplicate, I believe.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47366453/direct-initialization-vs-direct-list-initialization-c

Comment: Some fun and informative viewing: [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can C++ distinguish between () and {} when initialising a class?

Because they are using different syntaxes, so the compiler can parse them differently and behave accordingly.

> how can I create a constructor for both () and {} with different meanings?

Define 2 constructors, making one of them take a [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) as a parameter. `{}` will call that constructor.  `()` will call the other one.

Comment: Can you overload `{}` to take some other parameter, or is it hard coded to `std::initializer_list`?

Comment: `{}` itself (ie, a *braced-init-list*) has no type, so you can't overload on it. But it can be used to initialize an `initializer_list` object, which you can overload on.