# Is direct-initialization equivalent to direct-list-initialization?

Tags: c++, initialization, list-initialization, direct-initialization

I have the following example:

```
struct S{
   int x, y;
}

S s1{1};    // direct-initialization or direct-list-initialization ?
S s2{1, 2}; // direct-initialization or direct-list-initialization ?
S s3(1);    // direct-initialization or direct-list-initialization ?
S s4(1, 2); // direct-initialization or direct-list-initialization ?
int i1{10}; // direct-initialization or direct-list-initialization ?
int i2(10); // direct-initialization or direct-list-initialization ?
```

My questions

- I just need to know what's the type of initialization in the above statements?
- Is there any standard quote applied here?

I am already checked the question [direct-initialization vs direct-list-initialization (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47366453/16972547), but it hasn't strict answer yet.

Comment: These are the exact rules: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#general-16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [direct initialization's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization):

> `T object ( arg );`
>
> `T object ( arg1, arg2, ... );`
> **(1)**
>
> `T object { arg };`    **(2)**     (since C++11)
>
> `T ( other )`
>
> `T ( arg1, arg2, ... )`
> **(3)**

> **Direct initialization** is performed in the following situations:
>
> - 1. initialization with a nonempty parenthesized list of expressions or braced-init-lists (since C++11)
> - 2. initialization of an object of non-class type with a single brace-enclosed initializer (note: **for class types and other uses of braced-init-list, see list-initialization**)
> - 3. initialization of a prvalue temporary (until C++17)the result object of a prvalue (since C++17) by functional cast or with a parenthesized expression list

And from [List initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

**Direct-list-initialization**

> `T object { arg1, arg2, ... };`   **(1)**
>
> `T { arg1, arg2, ... }`   **(2)**

---

Now we can use the above to answer your question.

```
S s1{1};    // direct-list-initialization from direct-list init point 1 above
S s2{1, 2}; // direct-list-initialization from direct-list init point 1 above
S s3(1);    // direct-initialization from direct init point 1 above
S s4(1, 2); // direct-initialization from direct init point 1 above
int i1{10}; // direct-initialization from direct init point 2 above
int i2(10); // direct-initialization from direct init point 1 above
```

Comment: It's appeared to me that `T object {arg}` (only one `arg`), if `T` is of class type, then `T object {arg}` will be *direct-list-initialization* and if `T` is of non-class type, then `T object {arg}` will be *direct-initialization*. Right?

Comment: @SofaJoe Yes. This is also evident from two of the examples. `S s1{1};` is direct-list initialization while `int i1{10};` is direct-initialization.